# How to hold a reference to broadcast variable

Tags: apache-spark

Where, in a scala application, is the best place to store a Spark `broadcast` variable, so that it can be referenced elsewhere in the app?

```
val broadcast:Broadcast = ...
```

It does not appear to be possible to save it in an `Object`, because:

- an object cannot have an uninitialized variable, so it cannot be
  passed a reference to the broadcast variable by calling a method on the object to set the reference.
- an Object cannot setup the broadcast variable
  itself, as an object has no constructor into which to pass a
  reference to the SparkContext.

Thanks

Comment: and so what is the question ?

Comment: How can I save a reference to a broadcast variable in a Scala application, so that it can be accessed elsewhere in the application (functions passed to rdd's which live in different classes). If you have some example code it is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `var` rather than a `val` is likely the solution.

The following is one approach. In the example, the broadcast variable is being used to hold a cache.

```
Object Cache {

 private var cache:Broadcast;

 // This method must be called by client to initialize the cache
 def init(sc:SparkContext) = {
   cache = sc.broadcast(loadCache)
 }

 def getCache() = {
  // check that variable is initialized
  if cache!=null {
    Some(cache)   
  }
  else
  {
     None
  }
 }

 private def loadCache():List[String] = {
    // load data from DB
 }

}
```